# PC has to be booted twice for monitor to become enabled

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

After installing a Zotac GeForce GT 640 2GB Edition, I now have my monitor plugged in to the DVI port. However, when I boot my PC the monitor doesn't come on after BIOS or POST. I have to reboot the PC and then the monitor kicks in. This never happened when I was using the integrated nForce 430 GPU.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

**Edit**: I've switched the primary display in the BIOS to PCI_E, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: I'm sure you thought to check the manufacturers website for updated drivers =]

Comment: @Tyson since the issue happens even at POST, drivers won't fix anything... What is your power supply ?

Comment: AcBel 250W max, apparently.

Comment: I don't see why that has to do with the PC being booted twice in order for the display to initialize though.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Good call.  [Zotac recommends 350W](http://zotacusa.com/geforce-gt-640-zt-60201-10l.html).

Comment: Could it be that there isn't enough power going to the card initially?

Comment: @DarkWolffe Quite possibly; even if not, you don't want to run your system that way.

Comment: Understandable. I found [this PSU upgrade](http://www.ebay.com/itm/290789389160) which I'll be picking up. If it does work and you put your two cents in as a possible answer, I'll award you with the bounty.

Comment: Did you uninstall the old driver and install the new afterwards? It could be windows is unaware of the change and still tries to send the image to the nForce. Happened to me also some years ago when I first installed Windows before the GeForce.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the VGA cable has been removed from the monitor.

If this still doesn't resolve the problem, use the buttons on the monitor to change the input from Auto-detect (or Automatic) to DVI (or Digital).

Comment: There is no VGA cable anywhere in this system. Furthermore, the monitor displays the BIOS and POST outputs, as detailed above. Answer does not solve the issue.

Comment: @DarkWolffe Connecting two video cables is a common mistake.  Your question doesn't it make it clear that you had video up to some point where Windows was starting.  Remember, these answers are here to help others with similar issues.